# Receiving DB update events in .NET from SQLite

Tags: .net, sqlite, notifications, filesystemwatcher, system.data.sqlite

I've recently discovered the awesomeness of SQLite, specifically the .NET wrapper for SQLite at http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/.

Now, suppose I'm developing software that will be running on multiple machines on the same network. Nothing crazy, probably only 5 or 6 machines. And each of these instances of the software will be accessing an SQLite database stored in a file in a shared directory (is this a bad idea? If so, tell me!).

Is there a way for each instance of the app to be notifiied if one instance updates the database file? One obvious way would be to use the `FileSystemWatcher` class, read the entire database into a DataSet, and then ... you know ... enumerate through the entire thing to see what's new ... but yeah, **that seems pretty idiotic, actually.** Is there such a thing as a provider of SQLite updates?

Does this even make sense as a question? I'm also pretty much a newbie when it comes to ADO.NET, so I might be approaching the problem from the entirely wrong angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SQLite across a network isn't a good idea. Check out SQLite's own recommendations on this [here](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

A client-server database will be far more reliable and may also solve your notification problem. For instance, PostgreSQL has an inter-client signalling mechanism via the NOTIFY and LISTEN statements, which can be used directly from a client or from inside a function, sproc or trigger.

Even if you decide to go for SQLite, do not use file-watching APIs. They are completely broken on Windows due to a race-condition deep in the bowels of the filesystem. From the MSDN entry for [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx):

> Note that a FileSystemWatcher  does not raise an Error event when an event is missed or when the buffer size is exceeded, due to dependencies with the Windows operating system.

It offers recommendations to alleviate this, but none of them provides any relibility guarantees.

Comment: @Marcelo: Thanks for your input. At first it seemed like SQLite offered a great way to share data between processes without having to install a client-server database. Now it's starting to look like that is really the only way to do this right. I'll probably accept this answer shortly after looking into it a bit more myself.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't any built-in mechanism to hook into some sort of change event you can detect changes in a SQLite database across multiple processes.

A SQLite database should not be shared over a network share for multiple reasons as explained by the creators here: https://www.sqlite.org/useovernet.html

It is far more efficient and consistent if you have a server running a TCP client server app that receives your requests and sends the data as a response.

### Polling the file header

The SQLite file header contains the field [File change counter](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#file_change_counter) which gets updated whenever the database or its tables have been modified. We can use polling on the header to detect changes. I don't know why so many people are against polling, it is perfectly normal in low-level programming and if a software or hardware does not provide any interrupt you are stuck with polling anyway.

**SQLiteHeader struct**

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The first 100 bytes of the database file comprise 
/// the database file header. The database file header 
/// is divided into fields as shown by the <see cref="SQLiteHeader"/> struct. 
/// All multibyte fields in the database file header 
/// are stored with the most significant byte first (big-endian).
/// The <see cref="SQLiteHeader"/> already checks for endianess and
/// converts the mulitbyte fields for you.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe public struct SQLiteHeader
{       
    public static SQLiteHeader FromFile(string fileName, out SQLiteHeaderError error)
    {
        return SQLiteHeaderParser.FromFile(fileName, out error);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The header string: "SQLite format 3\000"
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string HeaderString;
    /// <summary>
    /// The database page size in bytes. 
    /// Must be a power of two between 512 and 32768 inclusive, 
    /// or the value 1 representing a page size of 65536.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public short PageSize;
    /// <summary>
    /// File format write version. 1 for legacy; 2 for WAL.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(18)]
    public byte WriteVersion;
    /// <summary>
    /// File format read version. 1 for legacy; 2 for WAL.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(19)]
    public byte ReadVersion;
    /// <summary>
    /// Bytes of unused "reserved" space at the end of each page. Usually 0.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public byte Reserved;
    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum embedded payload fraction. Must be 64.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(21)]
    public byte MaxPayloadFract;
    /// <summary>
    /// Minimum embedded payload fraction. Must be 32.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(22)]
    public byte MinPayloadFract;
    /// <summary>
    /// Leaf payload fraction. Must be 32.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(23)]
    public byte LeafPayloadFract;
    /// <summary>
    /// File change counter.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public Int32 FileChangeCounter;
    /// <summary>
    /// Size of the database file in pages. 
    /// The "in-header database size".
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public Int32 InHeaderDatabaseSize;
    /// <summary>
    /// Page number of the first freelist trunk page.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public Int32 FirstFreeListTrunkPage;
    /// <summary>
    /// Total number of freelist pages.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(36)]
    public Int32 NumFreeListPages;
    /// <summary>
    /// The schema cookie.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(40)]
    public Int32 SchemaCookie;
    /// <summary>
    /// The schema format number. 
    /// Supported schema formats are 1, 2, 3, and 4.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(44)]
    public Int32 SchemaFormatNumber;
    /// <summary>
    /// Default page cache size.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(48)]
    public Int32 PageCacheSize;
    /// <summary>
    /// The page number of the largest root b-tree 
    /// page when in auto-vacuum or incremental-vacuum modes, 
    /// or zero otherwise.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(52)]
    public Int32 MaxRootBTreePage;
    /// <summary>
    /// The database text encoding. 
    /// A value of 1 means UTF-8. 
    /// A value of 2 means UTF-16le. 
    /// A value of 3 means UTF-16be.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(56)]
    public Int32 TextEncoding;
    /// <summary>
    /// The "user version" as read and set 
    /// by the user_version pragma.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(60)]
    public Int32 UserVersion;
    /// <summary>
    /// True (non-zero) for incremental-vacuum mode. 
    /// False (zero) otherwise.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(64)]
    public Int32 IncrementalVacuumMode;
    /// <summary>
    /// The "Application ID" set by 
    /// PRAGMA application_id.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(68)]
    public Int32 ApplicationId;
    /// <summary>
    /// Reserved for expansion. Must be zero.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(72)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public string ReservedExpansion;
    /// <summary>
    /// The version-valid-for number.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(92)]
    public Int32 VersionValidFor;
    /// <summary>
    /// SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(96)]
    public Int32 SQLiteVersionNumber;        
}
```

**SQLiteHeaderParser class**

```cs
internal static class SQLiteHeaderParser
{
    internal static readonly byte[] MagicHeaderBytes = new byte[] {
        0x53, 0x51, 0x4c, 0x69,
        0x74, 0x65, 0x20, 0x66,
        0x6f, 0x72, 0x6d, 0x61,
        0x74, 0x20, 0x33, 0x00
    };


    private static void ToLittleEndian(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)
    {
        switch (length)
        {
            case 2:
                {
                    ushort num = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, offset);
                    num = (ushort)(
                        ((num & 0xff) >> 8) |
                         (num << 8)
                    );
                    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
                    bytes.CopyTo(buffer, offset);
                    break;
                }
            case 4:
                {
                    uint num = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, offset);
                    num = (uint)(
                        ((num & 0xff000000) >> 24) |
                        ((num & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) |
                        ((num & 0x0000ff00) << 8) |
                         (num << 24)
                    );
                    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
                    bytes.CopyTo(buffer, offset);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }


    private static int GetOffset(string name)
    {
        return Marshal.OffsetOf<SQLiteHeader>(name).ToInt32();
    }        


    private static void SetEndianess(byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (!(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)) {
            return;
        }

        SQLiteHeader h = new SQLiteHeader();

        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.PageSize)),               Marshal.SizeOf(h.PageSize));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.FileChangeCounter)),      Marshal.SizeOf(h.FileChangeCounter));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.InHeaderDatabaseSize)),   Marshal.SizeOf(h.InHeaderDatabaseSize));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.FirstFreeListTrunkPage)), Marshal.SizeOf(h.FirstFreeListTrunkPage));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.NumFreeListPages)),       Marshal.SizeOf(h.NumFreeListPages));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.SchemaCookie)),           Marshal.SizeOf(h.SchemaCookie));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.SchemaFormatNumber)),     Marshal.SizeOf(h.SchemaFormatNumber));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.PageCacheSize)),          Marshal.SizeOf(h.PageCacheSize));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.MaxRootBTreePage)),       Marshal.SizeOf(h.MaxRootBTreePage));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.TextEncoding)),           Marshal.SizeOf(h.TextEncoding));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.PageCacheSize)),          Marshal.SizeOf(h.PageCacheSize));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.UserVersion)),            Marshal.SizeOf(h.UserVersion));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.IncrementalVacuumMode)),  Marshal.SizeOf(h.IncrementalVacuumMode));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.ApplicationId)),          Marshal.SizeOf(h.ApplicationId));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.VersionValidFor)),        Marshal.SizeOf(h.VersionValidFor));
        ToLittleEndian(buffer, GetOffset(nameof(h.SQLiteVersionNumber)),    Marshal.SizeOf(h.SQLiteVersionNumber));
    }


    private static byte[] PrepareHeader(BinaryReader reader, out SQLiteHeaderError error)
    {
        int hdrSize = Marshal.SizeOf<SQLiteHeader>();
        byte[] buffer = reader.ReadBytes(hdrSize);

        var loadedMagicHeader = buffer.Take(MagicHeaderBytes.Length).ToArray();
        if (!(loadedMagicHeader.SequenceEqual(MagicHeaderBytes))) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("magic number miss match -> invalid header");
            error = SQLiteHeaderError.InvalidMagicNumber;
            return new byte[0];
        }

        SetEndianess(buffer);
        error = SQLiteHeaderError.Success;
        return buffer;
    }


    private static SQLiteHeader BufferToHeader(byte[] buffer)
    {
        GCHandle gchHeader = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        SQLiteHeader hdr = Marshal.PtrToStructure<SQLiteHeader>(gchHeader.AddrOfPinnedObject());
        gchHeader.Free();

        return hdr;
    }


    public static SQLiteHeader FromFile(string filePath, out SQLiteHeaderError error)
    {
        if (!(File.Exists(filePath))) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("invalid file path");
            error = SQLiteHeaderError.FileNotFound;
            return default(SQLiteHeader);
        }

        int hdrSize = Marshal.SizeOf<SQLiteHeader>();

        var fInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (fInfo.Length < hdrSize) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("not enough bytes");
            error = SQLiteHeaderError.InvalidHeaderSize;
            return default(SQLiteHeader);
        }

        byte[] buffer;
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(
                filePath, 
                FileMode.Open, 
                FileAccess.Read, 
                FileShare.ReadWrite, hdrSize))
            {
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                {
                    buffer = PrepareHeader(reader, out error);
                    if (buffer.Length < 1) {                   
                        return default(SQLiteHeader);
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            error = SQLiteHeaderError.Undefined;
            return default(SQLiteHeader);
        }

        SQLiteHeader header = BufferToHeader(buffer);
        return header;
    }
}
```

**SQLiteHeaderError enum**

```cs
[Flags]
public enum SQLiteHeaderError
{
    Success             = 0,
    FileNotFound        = 1 << 1,
    InvalidHeaderSize   = 1 << 2,
    InvalidMagicNumber  = 1 << 3,
    Undefined           = 1 << 8
}
```

**SQLiteChangeMonitor class**

```cs
public class SQLiteChangeMonitor : IDisposable
{
    private string          _sqliteFile;
    private SQLiteHeader    _sqliteHeader;

    private Timer _pollingTimer;

    private int _fileChangeCounter = -1;

    private static CancellationTokenSource  _cancelTokenSource;
    private static CancellationToken        _cancelToken;       


    private event EventHandler _onChangeDetected;
    public event EventHandler ChangeDetected
    {
        add {
            _onChangeDetected += value;
        }
        remove { 
            _onChangeDetected -= value; 
        }
    }


    //
    // Check for any changes in the header and restart timer.
    //
    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)state;
        if (autoEvent == null) {
            return;
        }
        CheckForChanges();
        autoEvent.Set();
    }


    //
    // Check if the file change counter of the header has changed
    // and fire event to signal change.
    //
    private void CheckForChanges()
    {
        if (_cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            SQLiteHeaderError err;
            _sqliteHeader = SQLiteHeader.FromFile(_sqliteFile, out err);
            int fcc = _sqliteHeader.FileChangeCounter;
            if (fcc != _fileChangeCounter)
            {
                _fileChangeCounter = fcc;
                _onChangeDetected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            // Implement your error handling here.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }   


    //
    // Start the System.Threading.Timer
    //
    private void StartPolling(int timeout)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        _pollingTimer = new Timer(TimerCallback, autoResetEvent, 0, timeout);
        autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }


    //
    // Get current change counter from file header to 
    // avoid missfire when starting the polling.
    //
    private void SetInitalChangeCounter()
    {
        SQLiteHeaderError err;
        _sqliteHeader = SQLiteHeader.FromFile(_sqliteFile, out err);
        _fileChangeCounter = _sqliteHeader.FileChangeCounter;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Starts polling for database changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pollingInterval">
    /// The polling interval in milliseconds</param>
    public void Start(int pollingInterval = 1000)
    {
        SetInitalChangeCounter();
        StartPolling(pollingInterval);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Stops polling for changes.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancelTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
    
    
    //
    // Set up cancellation token to end polling.
    //
    private void InitToken()
    {
        _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _cancelToken = _cancelTokenSource.Token;
    }


    public SQLiteChangeMonitor(string databaseFile)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseFile)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(
                nameof(databaseFile), 
                "Database file path cannot be null or empty."
            );
        }

        if (!(File.Exists(databaseFile))) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                "Unable to locate file.", 
                databaseFile
            );
        }

        _sqliteFile = databaseFile;

        InitToken();
    }


    ~SQLiteChangeMonitor() { Dispose(false); }
    public void Dispose() { Dispose(true); }
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        
        _cancelTokenSource?.Cancel();            
        _pollingTimer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

### High frequency polling

The `SQLiteChangeMonitor` class uses a default polling interval of 1000ms (1s). For high frequency polling intervals I'd recommend a pattern as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23341005/22191764

---

### Drawbacks

This does not provide any information about **what** has been modified but it is still far more efficient to poll the header and then update your DB views then always running queries against your DB and eventually updating your view.