# C# add listener to external API property

Tags: c#, external, event-listener

I'm writing a plugin for a tool using the tool's plugin API. The API provides several callbacks for important events, like objects created or modified. However, unfortunately this API doesn't seem very consistent, so the event doesn't fire for some properties that I would need to listen to.

Is there a way to react to methods of external API classes being called without direct code access? I know that classes can be extended, but I'm not aware of altering existing properties. Also the API classes are sealed and methods are not virtual, so no way of overriding.

The API is closed-source, so nothing else I can do here really. The developers don't seem to be supporting their API anymore, so there's little hope for them to implement these changes, so I have to look for workarounds. I would be glad for any kind of example on how to accomplish this, if at all possible.

Example of pseudo-code on what I would like to accomplish:

```
public class ApiClass // the class I have no code access to but is exposed via the API
{
     public void SomeMethod() {  } // this method is called via the tool's interface, this event I want to hook into
}

public class MyClass // my code
{
    private MethodListener myMethodListener = new MethodListener();

    public void init(ApiClass obj)
    {
        myMethodListener.register(obj.SomeMethod, MyCallback)
    }

    public void MyCallback() 
    {
        // some stuff I want to do after the tool called SomeMethod()
    }
}
```

So whenever the tool itself internally calls it's `SomeMethod()` I want to be executing my own code. I do not wish to alter the original methods arguments or return values or flow of execution, I simply want to react to it being called.

One possibility would propably be decompiling the API assembly, modify it and recompile to use in my plugin, but I would rather want to avoid that.

Comment: Make [mcve] and send bug report with not firing notification to developer. Until it's fixed use workarounds, e.g. use polling for detecting changes or use wrapper to rise missing changes after delay for known scenarios.

Comment: There's no example I could make for anyone to reproduce, this is about the core problem that's expressent in the post's title.
I would be glad however, for any examples about poling or using wrappers that you've mentioned, as this is exactly what I'm looking for as answer to my question.

Comment: See [polling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23340894/1997232), [wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/889160/1997232) on SO, should be more. Or on wiki: [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)), [wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function).

Comment: I have provided and extended an example to try and get accross what I mean/need. I don't see where wrappers would be helpful in this case and polling seems too low-level, at least in the example you've provided, so I have no idea how I could leverage this approach for my use-case.

Comment: Usually it is possible by means of a `SomePropertyChanged` or `PropertyChanged event` on the `ApiClass` type. Otherwise, if the class is **not** `sealed` and the property is `virtual`, you can try creating a derived class with an `override` of the property, and instantiate objects of that custom class instead of the original one. Another approach is by using some **existing** class designed specifically to listen on `ApiClass` changes. If none of the options are possible, you probably cannot accomplish the requested task.

Comment: @Rubidium37 the class is not sealed, but it's methods and properties aren't virtual either, so I don't thing derriving or wrapping the API class could help, as the tool would still be calling it's original methods. I've edited my post with hopefully a better example and explanation as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/interception-in-net-part-4-an-interception-framework) which describes crating a dynamic proxy to wrap an object instance and intercept method calls, then forwarding them on with [DynamicObject.TryInvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvokemember?view=net-8.0).

There a bunch of downsides to that such as the object being [Dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=net-8.0) so intellisense goes out the window, and it invokes everything via reflection which has an overhead.

But if it digs you out of a hole...

Comment: I don't seem to grasp the concept, or it doesn't apply to my use-case and I fail to express what I'm trying to do. A quick rundown: I use the tool, click on a button, the tool calls a method which is known to my plugin through the API, I want to execute code exactly on that method call after the button press. In the article, a dynamic proxy is created and the method to be intercepted is called on the proxy "by myself", so my own code. But the method I need to intercept is called by the tool on a button press. So I don't want to alter the original method, just react to it being called.

Comment: @AlexM If you need to perform something **after** the method call, maybe you can try attaching to the button's `Click` event. It should work if: 1) You want the method to run as usual; 2) you want to perform your task after the method; 3) you are sure that on each click the method is called once; 4) no other relevant operation is performed by the built-in click handler after the method call; 5) You can reach the button instance (querying child controls or in case through Reflection), or ...; 6) You can attach an handler to the `Click` event by other means.

Comment: @Rubidium37 none of the tools' GUI elements are exposed through the API, so no chance to hook into button events. I really only got the data objects and their properties/methods via the API that both the tool (e.g. via button clicks) and my plugin (with any custom logic I need to perform) operate on. Besides, there are other events the tool changes some data objects as well, I just choose button clicks as a simplified example.

Comment: I see. Yes, you’re going to have to get your hands dirty. 

The concept / library you want to research  is “detours”, which lets you inject your own code into the execution path of code you don’t control (“detouring” the code flow away from its original destination into you”)

Comment: This library claims to do it for .net code. I’ve not tried it. 
https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony. You would detour the original code into one of your methods, which would do what you want then call the original method (or call the original first, whichever works for you)

Comment: This sounds pretty much what I'd need, thank you very much! I'll be giving it a try and come back to this topic.